# Cannot find Plugin [id: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow', version: '5.2.0']

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm currently trying to create a simple discord bot. I finished the code and I'm trying to export it through shadow--> shadowJar. I keep getting this error message:

Plugin [id: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow', version: '5.2.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow:com.github.johnrengelman.shadow.gradle.plugin:5.2.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

I've tried to look up how to fix this, being pretty unsuccessful. I'm very new to this, only having experience with simple Java, like multi-dimensional arrays, classes, objects, etc.

Please help!

Here's my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.2.0"
}

mainClassName = "Main"

group 'com.mywebsite'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'



sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:3.5.0_329'
}
```

---

Answer (score -1):

At the time of writing this answer, [the shadow plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.plugin-shadow)'s latest version is `2.0.3`.

So I have no idea where you sourced that `5.2.0` from but this is the issue: there is no shadow plugin version `5.2.0` out there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I looked at [this link](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow), which threw me off.