# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError only in command line with Gradle Build

Tags: java, gradle, jar

i have been trying for several hours to get my java program to run via commandline using "java -jar myFile.jar arg1 arg2 ...", but i ONLY get this error when running via command line.
Additionally the program has a UI interface (with Swing), which runs without problems.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row
        at CSV2Excel.NewJFrame.main(NewJFrame.java:467)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'CSV2Excel.NewJFrame'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { $it.getName() }.join(' '),
            'Main-Class': 'CSV2Excel.NewJFrame',
        )
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation     'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20200518'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-excelant:4.1.2'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.3'
}
```

If I specify the individual jars instead of "configurations.compile.collect { $it.getName() }.join(' ')" in the Classpath, I get the error that no Main-Class attribute is stored.

I am a complete beginner when it comes to Gradle.

Thank you very much.

Edit:
i am using netbeans to build my project, which gives me a zip file with a bin and lib directory with all necessary libs in it.

Comment: Do you need to use `java -jar ...` as a requirement? If not, the Gradle application plugin will build a zip file which contains both dependency jars and a script that sets the classpath etc. If you need to pursue `java -jar`, the following example might be helpful (I don't have time to write it up, sadly... but the `MyBuild` task is key) - https://github.com/peidevs/WarO_Groovy/blob/1c69207eb9abf04e37b28b1e2d26818f39fef4d0/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the fatJar. Unfortunately I couldn't get it done with the custom Gradle Task either. 
In the end I used a Gradle Plugin for building fat Jars frome here https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/ and everything worked fine.
example with wrong versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065293/cannot-find-plugin-id-com-github-johnrengelman-shadow-version-5-2-0 for some future people with the same problem